# Generating E-pin or random Unique Number in PHP MYsql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was searching for a php script which could generate a unique 10 digit number (numerical) for my project.

I know very little about Php and here is my code, please help.

Code here is to generate a Random pin and store in database table lucky_coupon_pins.

---

//check for generate button

```
    if (isset($_POST['generate_pin'])) {
```

//generate a random number

```
    $random_number=mt_rand();
```

//once the code is generated check if it exists in table , if so generate again else move on

```
$row_count = $db->row_count("SELECT * FROM " . config_item('cart', 'table_lucky_coupon_pins') . " WHERE lucky_pin = '" . $random_number . "'");

if($row_count>0)

{
$random_number=mt_rand();
$row_count = $db->row_count("SELECT * FROM " . config_item('cart', 'table_lucky_coupon_pins') . " WHERE lucky_pin = '" . $random_number . "'");
}
```

//insert to database

```
$values = array(
                'lucky_pin'         => $random_number,
                'lucky_pin_value' => $_POST['lucky_pin_value']

            );      

            $db->insert(config_item('cart', 'table_lucky_coupon_pins'), $values);
```

---

Here I am checking the generated pin for once, if it already exists another pin is generated..I do not know how far is this unique, also the generated pin is sometimes 9 digit and sometimes its 10 digit.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) mt_rand() takes two parameters, a min and a max value, so to get a 10 digit random value, use either:

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

or

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1,9);
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $random_number .= mt_rand(0,9)
}
```

Is it unique? As it is, it is with high probability, but not for sure. (You only check once if it already exists.) You might consider using a loop e.g.

```
$row_count = 1;
while ($row_count > 0) {
    $random_number = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); // i prefer the other option but this one is somehow shorter
    $row_count = $db->row_count("SELECT * FROM " . config_item('cart', 'table_lucky_coupon_pins') . " WHERE lucky_pin = '" . $random_number . "'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mt_rand()` is supposed to be pretty good (or the best way to return random number using native php function), so have some faith in it. Also if you want 10 digit number only, try:

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for generating pin codes

```
function GeneratePinCode($chars){
    $pin="";
    while ($chars!=0){
        $pin .=rand(0,9);
        $chars--;
    }
    return $pin;
}
```

As for the uniqueness of the pin code, you can store each pin that you generate in the database and run a check each time you generate a new one.

Comment: $pin = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $digits; $i++)
            $pin .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        return $pin;